# Using Linq to Objects with Certain Collections - 'Select' not found

Tags: linq-to-objects

I have run into a few instances of collections that do not seem to support Linq to Objects.  Most recently, working with the default ASP.Net Membership Provider, this code:

```
var membershipUsers = (from m in Membership.FindUsersByName(userName) select m);
```

produces the compiler error

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type
>   'System.Web.Security.MembershipUserCollection'.  'Select' not found. 
>   Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'm'.

Where do implementations of the query pattern reside?

Can I create my own implementation?  How?

How can I "explicitly specify" the type of the range variable, and will that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the problem with this collection is that it implements the non generic IEnumberable interface. Linq extension methods don't apply for this non generic interface and that's why your code doesn't compile.
There are two things you can do here. First check out [this link](http://msmvps.com/blogs/matthieu/archive/2009/04/01/how-to-use-linq-extension-methods-on-non-generic-ienumerable.aspx), it has an implementation of the linq methods for this non generic interface.

Another solution could be to use the Cast method that IEnumerable does have:

```
 var linqableMembershipUsers = membershipUsers.Cast<MembershipUser>();
```

Now you can use which ever linq method you want.